# Is there a way to create stub for not yet implemented methods of an Interface?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When you add an interface to a class (ex: *Implements IAppController*), Visual Studio tells you immediately that some methods are missing, and it even tells you what are their name and signature...

Is there a way to ask VS to create those missing methods as stub?

Comment: If i get you, you can right click on Interface Name where you are implementing and select Implement Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a so-called "Smart-Tag" under the inteface declaration. Activate it and choose "Implement Interface...". See [MSDN - How to: Implement Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1s9z1w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for further reference.